# Problem with an array printing "random" values

Tags: c++, arrays

(C++) I am having a problem with my code and I don't know the reason why this could ever happen. Please help.

(EDIT) Here is the GamePlay.h, I think it is necessary for anyone looking over this in the future:

```
#ifndef GAMEPLAY_H
#define GAMEPLAY_H
#include "Card.h"
// #include "Player.h"
#include "Sensei.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;
class GamePlay
{
    private:

    Card playerCards[5];
    Card computerCards[5];
    int arr[3];

    public:

    GamePlay(Sensei, Player);
    int checkRoundWinner(int);
    void showCards();

};

#endif
```

This is my GamePlay Class:

```
#include
#include "GamePlay.h"
#include
using namespace std;

GamePlay::GamePlay(Sensei s, Player username)
{
// Card playerCards[5];
// Card computerCards[5];

//////////////////////////////////TEST
int arr[3];
for(int i = 0; i < 3; i++) //Assign test array
{
arr[i] = i*2;
}
cout << "___FIRST PRINT___" << endl;
for(int i = 0; i < 3; i++) //Print test array
{
cout << arr[i] << endl;
}
//////////////////////////////////TEST

// for(int i = 0; i < 5; i++) //Assign the arrays
// {
// playerCards[i] = s.getCards(username.getLevel(), i);
// computerCards[i] = s.getCards(username.getLevel(), i);
// }

}

int GamePlay::checkRoundWinner(int a) //Takes user chosen card...Compares card to the computer's chosen card
{
cout << "___SECOND PRINT___" << endl;
for(int i = 0; i < 3; i++) // Print test array again
{
cout << arr[i] << endl;
}

// playerCards[4].displayCard();
// int random = rand()%5;
// Card emptyCard("E",0);
// Card chosenCard = playerCards[a-1];
// cout << "Should be chosen card: ";
// playerCards[a-1].displayCard();
// cout << "Chosen card: ";
// chosenCard.displayCard();
// Card computerCard = computerCards[random];
// int chosenCardPower;
// int computerCardPower;

// if(chosenCard.getPowerLevel() != 0)
// {
// chosenCardPower = chosenCard.getPowerLevel();
// }else
// return 0; //Will have to check inside main if this 0 is returned (If the chosen card has already been used)

// while(computerCard.getElement() == "E")
// {
// random = rand()%5;
// computerCard = computerCards[random];//A random card from computerCards by using Math random function between 0-5
// }

// cout << "\nHere is your card: ";
// chosenCard.displayCard();
// cout << "\nHere is the computer's card: ";
// computerCard.displayCard();

// computerCardPower = computerCard.getPowerLevel();

// if(computerCardPower == chosenCardPower)
// {
// return 3;
// }
// else if(computerCardPower > chosenCardPower)
// {
// computerCards[random] = emptyCard;//Set that card in the computerCards array to an empty card
// return 2;
// }
// else
// {
// playerCards[a-1] = emptyCard;//Set that card in the playerCards array to an empty card
// return 1;
// }

}
```

This class has its own function, but the problem that I am having is that it seems my Card arrays (playerCards and computerCards) were being changed whenever I tried using them outside of the constructor.

To test that theory, I made a test array inside of my constructor and assigned variables to it. Then, I printed out the whole array inside the constructor. Then, I printed out the whole array again outside of the constructor (inside the checkRoundWinner method). And here is what printed:

```
___FIRST PRINT___
0
2
4
___SECOND PRINT___
6
32764
27533224
```

I did not make any alterations to the array before the second print. If you would like to see my Driver class, here it is:

```
#include
#include "Sensei.h"
#include "GamePlay.h"
#include "Player.h"
#include
#include
#include
#include
using namespace std;

int main()
{

Sensei mySensei;
Player newPlayer("Bob", "Bobb");


mySensei.welcomePlayer(newPlayer.getFirst(), newPlayer.getLast());

mySensei.readPack(); //Reads a card pack and assigns them to the arrays inside of mySensei

newPlayer.setLevel(1); //Changes the player level

//HERE IS WHEN THE PROBLEM OCCURS

GamePlay newGame(mySensei, newPlayer); //Make a new GamePlay (call the constructor)

int num = newGame.checkRoundWinner(1); //Call checkRoundWinner inside that GamePlay class and store the returned value

// if(num == 1)
// cout << "Comp wins." << endl;
// else if(num == 2)
// cout << "Player wins." << endl;
// else if(num == 3)
// cout << "TIE" << endl;
// else if(num == 0)
// cout << "CHANGE CARD" << endl;


}
```

Thank you for your time!

Comment: Hint: what’s `arr` and where is it defined?

Comment: Where does `arr` come from in the second printing? It's not the one you declared in the constructor

Comment: Why is there so much commented-out code?

Comment: Hey everyone, I'm new here and thank you so much for the help!

Comment: Sorry not seeing the relevance of being a new site member to why there is loads of commented-out code? Welcome though!

Comment: Ah, that was because this class had a whole other purpose, but I found I was having that array problem with it. And so...to test it, I decided to make a basic array. And then I commented out all other code so nothing could have a chance of interfering! :)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please [edit] your code to reduce it to a [mcve] of your problem.  Your current code includes loads of commented-out code that makes it harder to read

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Within the constructor

```
GamePlay::GamePlay(Sensei s, Player username)
{
// Card playerCards[5];
// Card computerCards[5];

//////////////////////////////////TEST
int arr[3];
//…
```

there is declared a local array that will not be alive after exiting the constructor.

So for example, the member function `checkRoundWinner` does not deal with the array declared in the constructor.

```
int GamePlay::checkRoundWinner(int a) //Takes user chosen card...Compares card to the computer's chosen card
{
cout << "___SECOND PRINT___" << endl;
for(int i = 0; i < 3; i++) // Print test array again
{
cout << arr[i] << endl;
}
```

If the class has the data member `arr` then you should remove the declaration of the local array.

```
int arr[3];
```

from the constructor.

Comment: Thank you! It works as intended now. Is there anything else I need to do? I'm new here.